# Wordpress - Change Authorlink to CPT ID

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

How can I change the author url to a cpt URL that I get from the USER META?

```
function my_author_link() {
    $_cptURL = get_post_permalink( '2349' );
    return home_url( $_cptURL );
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'my_author_link' );
```

How do I get the CPT ID from the USER META called _cptURL.

For more background...I like to create a band index site. The user registers and under the hood I create a new custom post type the the user...his BAND porfile page. The ID of the CPT (Band) I store in the USER META.

But how can I change the author link to the permalink of the CPT Band of this special user?

Thanks for help,
Denis

Comment: What is a "cpt URL"? How has it been defined? I think we're going to need more context.

Comment: Oh sorry...it is the PERMALINK of the Custom Post Type (Band) that I created after registration. I stored the postID in the user-meta field _cptURL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta), to get the meta value. The `'author_link'` filter also exposes the author ID to you (which you can use to get the meta for that specific user):

```
function my_author_link( $link, $author_id ) {       
    $link = get_user_meta( $author_id, '_cptURL', true );
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'my_author_link');
```

Comment: How do I get the $author_id? I tried this:    `function my_author_link() {
 global $post;
 /* $cpt_ID = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cptURL', true ); */
 $cpt_ID = get_user_meta($post->ID, '_cptID', true);
 $cpt_url = get_permalink( $guest_ID );
 return $cpt_url;
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'my_author_link' );` It seems to work.

Comment: Does my code not work? As I mentioned, the `$author_id` is exposed automatically by the filter.

Comment: When I use it it says Warning: **Missing argument 2 for my_author_link()**